# Showing that the inversion of a circle can be written in a certain way

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

Let $\phi = \dfrac{1}{r} ∘ T_{-O_C}$, $O_C$ the center of $C$, $T_{-O_C}$ is a translation.

I want to show that the inversion of a circle $C \in \mathbb{C}$ can be written as: $$\iota_C = \phi ∘ \iota ∘ \phi^{-1}$$

I have to show 3 things:

- $\forall z \in C$ , $\iota_C (z) \in C$
- $\iota_C$ exchanges the inside and the outside of C
- $\iota_C$ globally preserves the circles and the lines perpendicular to $C$

The first properties are easy to show but for the third property, I don't see why after  a homotheticity of $1/r$, and after a translation, a line $l$ perpendicular to $C$ remains the same

Comment: Also it is not clear what is a translation because they don't exist in hyperbolic geometry.

Comment: @Kii But some property states that any inverstion of a circle C ca be written as: $\iota_C = \Phi  ∘ \iota  ∘ \Phi$ where $\Phi$ is the composition oh a transmation and of a homothecity and where $\iota$ sends z on 1/z

Comment: Are you familiar with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation ?